# Do Wolverine's opponents bleed (and leave blood on the claws) in comics?

Tags: marvel, wolverine

As per [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/25199/why-doesnt-blood-stick-on-wolverines-blades), in the movies, they don't show blood on Wolverine's claws (because MPAA ratings would suffer otherwise).

The implication seems to be that this is endemic to movies, and not the case in comics.

Is that the case? **Do the comics routinely show blood, both in general when Wolverine stabs/slashes people, and most especially, on his claws**?

Any era answer will do, but I'm interested in "mainstream" X-men or wolverine ones, not some extra edgy/gritty niche arcs.

---

A negative answer should have some proof from out-of-universe statements from marvel-associated people. A positive answer should least (if possible give a screenshot/thumbnail) of at least 2-3 distinct examples from different comics/eras.

Comment: And the downvotes are for?

Comment: I don't know; asking for a list?

Comment: @MrLister - I'm asking for a Yes or No. Confirmed by examples if it's a "yes". That's not a list.

Comment: Well, in that case, the question "do the comics routinely show blood" sounds like it could well be a general reference question. I have no idea, mind you; I didn't read the comics, having grown up on the animated TV series, so just guessing. And I didn't do any of the downvoting.

Comment: @MrLister: I don't think there's such a thing as a "general reference" question about comics, because there's no generally-available reference source designed to answer questions about comics.

Comment: Only a +1 as this supports another question.

Comment: @DVK I didn't understand the downvotes too (when I first accessed this question the total was -1). That's a interesting question. BTW, +1 for you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, Wolverine's opponents do bleed, as would be expected by razor-sharp claws penetrating a person's skin, and there have been a number of comics featuring blood on the claws.

Even a cursory search for images of Wolverine shows his opponents bleeding, but one example is the [2nd printing variant of *Wolverine* #2](http://marvel.com/comic_books/issue/37966/wolverine_2010_2_2nd_printing_variant).

To give a few examples of comics that show blood on the actual claws, one needs to look no further than the covers of:

- [*X-Force Sex and Violence*](http://www.comicvine.com/x-force-sex-violence-chapter-one/37-224583/) #1 and its variant
- [*Wolverine: Bloody Choices*](http://marvel.wikia.com/Wolverine%3a_Bloody_Choices_Vol_1_1) Volume 1 #1
- [*Wolverine Origins*](http://marvel.com/comic_books/issue/29877/wolverine_origins_2006_50) #50
- [*Wolverine*](http://marvel.com/comic_books/issue/36720/wolverine_2010_2_vampire_variant) #2 Vampire Variant

Comment: Thanks. This strongly supports the answer in the linked question (since the comics obviously were not hesitant to show blood based on your links)

Comment: lol, I always thought this but just though maybe his claws are so sharp and smooth the blood just drips off almost as soon as they are drawn from the wound. Good answer though +1